# How to add Runtime environment in mobile first 7.1?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio, mobilefirst-appcenter

After installing MobileFirst Platform , It give No run time is there.
My configuration was given below:
1. WebSphere Application Server 8.5
2. Oracle 11g Enterprise edition
3. Mobile-first platform 7.1

Please help me to create Run-time in Mobile first Console.
From where I will download sample war file (for ex: project.war) for creating run-time environment.

Answer (score 1):

You have only mentioned "after installing IBM MobileFirst" and not exactly the steps followed. Configuring IBM MobileFirst Platform has two phases:

a) Installing the application binaries into the filesystem using Installation Manager.
b) Deploying MFP admin services and runtime in to an Application server using Server configuration tool or ANT scripts. The runtime war file needs to be created using IBM MFP Studio.

If you have not performed phase 2 or only installed admin services and not the runtime, go through the information in these links:

[Using server configuration tool](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/c_using_server_config_tool.html)

[Using ANT scripts to deploy](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/c_project_war_file_ant_tasks.html)

To get you started with various MFP 7.1 projects , you refer and use any of the sample applications available at [MFP 7.1 Getting started tutorials.](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/server-side-development/)

Once you have any of these sample projects loaded or a new project created in MFP studio, you can build the server side artefacts (adapters, application wlapps and runtime war) within the MFP studio or using ANT scripts:

Refer this link for further details and steps- [Deploy projects.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_deploy_projects.html)